# GET http://localhost//images/Products/ 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple angularjs html page that is retreiving some images from an api call.

```
<div class="col-xs-12" >
    <h3>Product List</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="productCtrl as ctrl" >
    <div class="well" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.products">
        <h3>
            <img style="float:left; height:80px; margin-right:10px" 
                ng-src="images/Products/{{item.Imagename  || '' }}" >
            <strong>{{item.Name}}</strong>
            <span class="pull-right label label-primary">
                {{item.Price | currency}}
            </span>
        </h3>
        <button ng-click="addProductToCart(item)" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
            Add to cart
        </button>
        <span class="small">{{item.Description}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works well and the data is displayed, however the images are not showing with a 403 forbidden error.

I tried to add permissions to IIS_IUSRS and Users(localPC) however I am still getting the same error.

Tried searching on Google and StackOverflow, however no solution solved my problem.

How can I solve this?

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Maybe Imagename is empty, so you try to display the folder itself, which of course won't work. Debug and see the actual values of Imagename  property.

Comment: 403 forbidden is entirely server side and a common user permissions issue - can you see the images when you visit them directly? (via url)

Comment: @brod yes when i type http://localhost/mystore/images/Products/adidasHoodie.jpg I can see the image

Comment: alrighty, sounds like Shadow Wizard is probably headed down the right path - check the variable outputs the correct information.

Comment: I'm quite new to angular.  How can I check if Imagename property is blank?  I am using Chrome.  How can I check in the web development console?

Comment: I also hardcoded the ng-src tag and its displaying the adidasHoodie.jpg, so yes most probably the Imagename is blank.  However when I console.log(data) on my controller, the imageName is not blank

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should work `<img [..] ng-src="{{item.Imagename && 'images/Products/' + item.Imagename  || '' }}" >`

With this modification, the content is empty until the data arrives.